# measure meters and speed that people walked using android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know if I can count how many meters walked and with what speed the user of a mobile phone using an android application. I know that, there are some apps that done this, but is it possible to develop this app by my self?

Does anyone can help me and give me some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of the following API's:

Detecting a walking user:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity#constant-summary

Speed and location tracking:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Good luck.